# $\sigma$-field generated by Borel sets

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

I what sense in the snippet is the $\sigma$-field $\cal M$ on $M$ generated by all the functions $$m\to m(C)$$
for $C$ Borel;how does $\cal M$ look like ?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Do you want to know what the definition of "a sigma-field generated by a set of functions" is?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M$ is the set of all counting measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}) $, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field.

For each $C \in \mathcal{B}$, define a function $f_C : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_C(m)=m(C)$.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the $\sigma$-field generate by the functions in $\{ f_C : C \in \mathcal{B}\}$.

It means that  $\mathcal{M}$ be the $\sigma$-field generate by the sets in $\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C \in \mathcal{B} , D\in \mathcal{B} \}$, in other words, $\mathcal{M}$ be the $\sigma$-field generate by the sets in $\{ \{m \in M : m(C) \in D \} : C, D \in \mathcal{B} \}$.

Using the properties of $\sigma$-field and Borel $\sigma$-field, we can simplify to:  $\mathcal{M}$ be the $\sigma$-field generate by the sets in $\{ \{m \in M : m(C) > a \} : C \in \mathcal{B} \textrm{ and } a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

**Remark 1**: Let us prove, step by step, that
$$\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C, D \in \mathcal{B} \}= \{ \{ m \in M : m(C) \in D \} : C, D \in \mathcal{B} \}$$

Note that, given any $ C, D \in \mathcal{B}$,
$$m \in  f_C^{-1}(D)  \Leftrightarrow (m \in M  \textrm{ and }  f_C(m) \in D) 
\Leftrightarrow (m \in M  \textrm{ and }  m(C) \in D)$$

So, for all $ C, D \in \mathcal{B}$, $$f_C^{-1}(D)  = \{ m \in M : m(C) \in D \}  \tag{1}$$  It follows that
$$\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C, D\in \mathcal{B}  \}= \{ \{ m \in M : m(C) \in D \} : C, D \in \mathcal{B} \}$$

**Remark 2**: Let us prove, step by step, that
\begin{align*}
\sigma(\{ \{ m \in M : m(C) \in D \} : & \, C, D \in \mathcal{B} \})= \\
&=\sigma(\{ \{m \in M : m(C) > a \} : C \in \mathcal{B} \textrm{ and } a \in \mathbb{R}\})
\end{align*}

First, let $\Gamma= \{(a,+\infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R} : a \in  \mathbb{R}\}$.
Note that $\mathcal{B}$ is generated by $\Gamma$, that is  $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\Gamma)$.

So, we must prove:
\begin{align*}
\sigma(\{ \{ m \in M : m(C) \in D \} : & \,C\in \mathcal{B} \textrm{ and } D\in \sigma(\Gamma) \})= \\ &=\sigma(\{ \{m \in M : m(C) \in D \} : C \in \mathcal{B} \textrm{ and } D \in \Gamma \}) 
\end{align*}

It means, using $(1)$:
$$ \sigma(\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C\in \mathcal{B}, D\in \sigma(\Gamma) \})= \sigma(\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C \in \mathcal{B}, D \in \Gamma \}) $$

Clearly,
$$\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C \in \mathcal{B}, D \in \Gamma \} \subseteq \{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C\in \mathcal{B}, D\in \sigma(\Gamma) \}$$

So, we have,

$$\sigma(\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C \in \mathcal{B}, D \in \Gamma \}) \subseteq \sigma (\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C\in \mathcal{B}, D\in \sigma(\Gamma) \})$$

Now, let us write $\Psi =\sigma (\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C\in \mathcal{B}, D\in \Gamma \})$.

For each  $C\in \mathcal{B}$, consider  $\Sigma_C = \{E \subseteq \mathbb{R}: f_C^{-1}(E) \in \Psi\}$. Using the properties on the inverse image and the fact that $\Psi$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it is easy to prove that $\Sigma_C$ is $\sigma$-algebra. It is also clear that $\Gamma \subset \Sigma_C$. So $\sigma(\Gamma) \subseteq \Sigma_C$.

It means that, for each $D\in \sigma(\Gamma)$ , $f_C^{-1}(D) \in \Psi$.
It means, for all  $C\in \mathcal{B}$, $$\{f_C^{-1}(D) : D\in \sigma(\Gamma)\} \subseteq \Psi$$
So
$$\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C\in \mathcal{B}, D\in \sigma(\Gamma) \} = \bigcup_{C\in \mathcal{B}}\{f_C^{-1}(D) : D\in \sigma(\Gamma)\} \subseteq \Psi$$

Since $\Psi$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have

$$\sigma (\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C\in \mathcal{B}, D\in \sigma(\Gamma) \}) \subseteq \Psi$$

Comment: Your answer has helped. I need though the step by step proof of these equalities:  $\{ f_C^{-1}(D) : C \in \mathcal{B} , D\in \mathcal{B} \}$ = $\{ m \in M : m(C) \in D \textrm{ where }C, D \in \mathcal{B} \}$ = 
$\{ m \in M : m(C) > a \textrm{ where }C \in \mathcal{B} \textrm{ and } a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @user852508 I corrected a typo in my answer. There were $\{\}$ missing in two places.

Comment: @user852508 I added two detailed remarks. I hope it helps.

Comment: Right, this are the places that were unclear to me. Could you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932195/papangelous-formula-and-e) which is a question from the same book as the one above ?