# Papangelou's formula and $E$

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, expected-value

I was given the following hint for Papangelou's formula from the snippet below, but I do not follow from it this implication:
3.3.7 $\Longrightarrow $ 3.3.8.
The reverse implication is clear to me from the hint.
In particular how is used the boundedness of $f$ ?

It is unfortunate to call the state space of $Z(t)$ as it is the same letter as for expected value.

**Hint:**

Here, it is said that the ESTA property $E_N^0[f(Z(0))] = E[f(Z(0))]$ holds if and only if
the lack of bias condition (3.3.8) is satisfied.
This is verified from (3.3.7) as follows.
On the right hand side of (3.3.7),
$E[f(Z(0)) \lambda(0)] = E[f(Z(0)) E[\lambda(0) | Z(0)]] = \lambda E[f(Z(0))]$,
where (3.3.8) and $E[\lambda(0)] = \lambda$ are used in the second equality.

[image]

Comment: Can you give references of the book you mention ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes I can: Bremaud/Baccelli: Elements of Queueing Theory Palm Martingale Calculus. If you drop your email here, I can send you entire pdf.

Comment: Connected: corollary 1 in [this document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231649746_On_the_stationary_workload_distribution_of_work-conserving_single-server_queues_A_general_formula_via_stochastic_intensity) by Naoto Miyoshi,
Journal of Applied Probability
Vol. 38, No. 3 (Sep., 2001), pp. 793-798

Comment: @JeanMarie I've checked but it is not exactly the same thing in Miyoshi at first seeing.

Comment: @JeanMarie Please look at the edit. I was given some hint but I do not follow it.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have now proved 3.3.7. from 3.3.8. What about the opposite direction ? Also, how is the boundedness used here ?